# hashchange problem: loading javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

I have two pages and I am using hashchange on one of the divs

here is my problem I have a button inside the div that replaces the div on current page. I have used some event handling on my buttons using jquery, but after hashchange they look like normal buttons the javascript doesnot get applied to those buttons, how could I solve this problem?

any efforts appreciated thanks

Comment: .. don't style them with jquery ?  why not use css ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli .... I have on-rollover fadein and fadeout and I dont know if we can achieve that in only css

Comment: @Koool, ok.. but that is event handling, not styling..

Comment: okay I will modify my question

Comment: if you can post a working example at http://www.jsfiddle.net it would be the ideal..

Answer (score 0):

From the comment i undestand that the real issue is with the event handling (*on-rollover*) and not the styling..

For that you can use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) methods.

example

```
$('buttonselector').live('mousenter', function(){
  // do the fadein here
}).live('mouseleave',function(){
  // do the fadeout here
});
```

Comment: hey I am using it something like this  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').someFunction({  //function  });
  });